# Runtime Error 91 VBA: Looping through an Array passed to a custom Function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I don't understand why I have a runtime error and an explanation with suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have written a long macro that essentially uses the values in a sheet to calculate a scale of color, dependent upon the limits entered elsewhere on the sheet. What I need it to do is save the cells in a row from column 6 to 17 in an array and then later use that array to find the maximum or minimum value. I would have tried using WorksheetFunction.Max, but many of the values are going to contain letters (I have a custom function that converts the strings to decimals), and if there are any blanks in the middle of the range it causes an error. So I thought to circumvent that error by only finding the max of values that are not blank.

I am trying to do this: for every value in the array, use the conversion function, then return the largest one.

I need that to be a custom function to make Sub FormatReportCard() more readable, as I use the Max and Min function in multiple places and I use them to do math.

I have read a number of forum posts on this error, and I suspect that my array is "empty" causing the runtime error in the function, but I can't figure out why. I tried filling it with a dummy range, I've tried using the () or not using the () in various places. I tried switching different components with between Range and Variant. different variable types. I tried using a message box to tell me if the array gets anything assigned to it, but the runtime error prevents me from getting that far.

[!Here is a picture of the worksheet that gets formatted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJsWm.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJsWm.png)

```
Sub FormatReportCard()

Dim UpLimit As Single
Dim upConcern As Single
Dim midPoint As Single
Dim LowLimit As Single
Dim lowConcern As Single

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngWhite As Range
Dim size As Integer, rowi As Integer, i As Integer
Dim thisRow() As Range
size = 0
rowi = 0

For Each rng In Range("F5:Q11").Cells

    'Below, we check the row number. If we are on a new row, then we use a for
    'loop to set the size of an array. Then we use another for loop to store
    'all this row's cells for later use.
    If rowi <> rng.Row Then
        For Each rngWhite In Range(Cells(rng.Row, 6), Cells(rng.Row, 17))
            If rng.Value <> "" Then
                size = size + 1
            End If
        Next rngWhite
        ReDim thisRow(1 To size) As Range
        rowi = rng.Row
    End If
    If rowi <> rng.Row Then
        For Each rngWhite In Range(Cells(rng.Row, 6), Cells(rng.Row, 17))
            If rngWhite.Value <> "" Then
                Set thisRow(i) = rngWhite
                MsgBox (thisRow(i))
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next rngWhite
    End If

    '**Lots of activity that doesn't involve the array**

   midPoint = CustomMax(thisRow)

    '**Do math with the midPoint**

Next rng
End Sub

'_______________________________________________________________________________________________________

Function ConvertToDecimal(angleIn As String) As Variant
    '**Turns industry-specific string combinations into a decimal that can be used in calculations**
End Function

'_______________________________________________________________________________________________________

Function CustomMax(arrayIn() As Range) As Single

Dim i As Integer
Dim vout As Single
Dim flag As Boolean

     For i = LBound(arrayIn) To UBound(arrayIn)
        If Not flag Then
            vout = ConvertToDecimal(arrayIn(i).Value) '**here is where it tells me the object is not set**
            flag = True
        ElseIf ConvertToDecimal(arrayIn(i).Value) > vout Then
            vout = ConvertToDecimal(arrayIn(i).Value)
        End If
    Next i
CustomMax = vout

End Function
```

Comment: Instead of `For Each rng In Range("F5:Q11").Cells` it's easier to do `For Each rw In Range("F5:Q11").Rows` and then loop over the cells in `rw`.  Then you can skip the row-tracking stuff.

Comment: can you give an example of the data and expected output?

Comment: Maybe "if there are any blanks in the middle of the range it causes an error" is your problem. At which code line the error appears? If the `blanks` are problematic you must escape them and use only the appropriate data, I think.

Comment: Yes, that is the original problem. This is the original method of determining the midpoint:   `midPoint = WorksheetFunction.Max(ConvertToDecimal(Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value), ConvertToDecimal(Cells(rng.Row, 17).Value))`  Picture has been edited in. This is flawed because it uses only the first and last values.

Comment: You have CustomMax expecting an array of ranges, but you pass it a single multi cell range.  Change CustomMax to receive a single range and loop over its cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: your actual problem is likely this -

The first time you hit a new row this runs:

```
If rowi <> rng.Row Then
    For Each rngWhite In Range(Cells(rng.Row, 6), Cells(rng.Row, 17))
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
            size = size + 1
        End If
    Next rngWhite
    ReDim thisRow(1 To size) As Range
    rowi = rng.Row     '<<<< #########
End If
```

...but the last thing you do in that block is set `rowi = rng.Row`, so this following block never runs:

```
If rowi <> rng.Row Then
    For Each rngWhite In Range(Cells(rng.Row, 6), Cells(rng.Row, 17))
        If rngWhite.Value <> "" Then
            Set thisRow(i) = rngWhite
            MsgBox (thisRow(i))
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next rngWhite
End If
```

---

You can do something like this:

**EDIT** - now a bit closer to your original method...

```
Sub FormatReportCard()

    Dim rw As Range, n As Long, j As Long, v
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr, arr2()

    For Each rw In Range("F5:Q11").Rows
        n = Application.CountA(rw)        'any values?
        If n > 0 Then
            arr = rw.Value                'row as array
            ReDim arr2(1 To n)            'values-only array
            j = 0
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)   'fill arr2
                v = arr(1, i)
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    j = j + 1
                    arr2(j) = ConvertToDecimal(CStr(arr(1, i)))
                End If
            Next i
            Debug.Print "Row: " & rw.Row, Application.Max(arr2), Application.Min(arr2) '<<
        End If

        'etc etc

    Next rw

End Sub

Function ConvertToDecimal(angleIn As String) As Variant
    If Len(angleIn) > 0 Then
        ConvertToDecimal = CDbl(Replace(angleIn, "x", "")) 'for example
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was scratching my head trying to figure out why `Set thisRow(i) = rngWhite` wouldn't throw an error, `i` being equal to `0` on the first iteration and `thisRow` having a lower bound of `1`. I think  you found the reason why.

Comment: Okay, so the lower approach you suggested seems to have addressed the issue. A few type errors came up that were easily addressed by switching my variables to Doubles. But now my array is returning 0 when I take the min. I thought Max and Min were supposed to ignore blank entries and text entries, so I'm not sure where that 0 is coming from

Comment: Update: The 0's were a result of numbers not being converted to Doubles. The Max(Array) approach is working perfectly now. Thank you!